# whats wrong with AN??? why i cant animate values inside nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

Sometimes its works and sometimes doesnt works. I have no idea why. I did same. In left pick is all right. The value changes during the animation.
But in right pick is not okay! It just keeps the same value and I don't understand why. I tried several times to press "i" entered different values. Does not work!!!  This is some kind of nonsense.

[image]

upd:

Sorry guys. I have never been so butthurt about the blender. It was fixed by itself !!!! I tried closing and opening the blender, creating new files and doing the same node setups. And it did not work! And now I started shooting a video with a demonstration of this bug and it was fixed by itself. I don't understand how to study Animation Nodes if they work on their own. The whole evening I was dealing with this and it didn’t work, and now it’s fixed by itself. I don't understand >_<

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer that. Can you please tell us what you're trying to do first, because Blender is highly contextual. Unless it's a bug, things operate for a specific reason. So it may be just a matter of understanding what you're trying to do. Adn if you happen to have the blend with the explanation, thats always better.

Comment: Also, see [Node animation keys and curves not showing up in Graph Editor or Dope Sheet.](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/820).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue seems to be resolved according to the user's edit

Comment: I do not know how it works. But the problem was solved by itself. And it may appear again. I googled and saw a few mentions that people had similar. Perhaps this is not a problem with animation nodes, but some kind of blender bug that appears under certain rare conditions.